# What’s with the spherical basis vectors?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

My short [calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIySb.jpg) Regarding the representation of the point (1,1,0) in spherical coordinates led me to an error. Have I miscalculated or is my view on the point being specified by $r=\sqrt{2}$, $\phi= \pi/4$ and $\theta =\pi /2$ Somehow wrong in the first place?
My heads stuck for the moment :(

Comment: $r$ should be $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Yeah, typo, thx

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes. The first is that $r$ should be $\sqrt{2}$. The second, and perhaps more confusing thing is that in spherical coordinates, the radius vector $\mathbf{r}$ is simply $\mathbf{r} = r \mathbf{\hat{r}}$, it is NOT $ r \mathbf{\hat{r}} + \theta \mathbf{\hat{\theta}} +  \phi \mathbf{\hat{\phi}}$. This is a very common misconception.

So, yes, although the spherical coordinate representation of the point $p = (1,1,0)\in \Bbb{R}^3$ is $r=\sqrt{2}, \theta = \pi/2, \phi = \pi/4$, the radius vector is still
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r} &= \sqrt{2}\,\, \mathbf{\hat{r}}
\end{align}

Comment: This seems counterintuitive to me, as every vector in the R3 should be the linear combination of the three(!) basis vectors. As you state, it seems that the basis vectors of $\rho$ and $\theta$ are redundant in some way... is this because they are not constant through R3 and do depend on the angles?
Do you have any recommendations on further readings on the topic?

Comment: Another glimpse, that just came through my head: At each triplet (r,$\rho$,$\theta$), the corresponding basis vectors $\hat r, \hat \phi$ and $\hat \theta$ form a right hand coordinate system, that origins at the given point on the sphere. Is this somehow useful to declace right hand coordinate systems, that may be arbitrarily shifted and rotated from the origin of the cartesian coordinate system?

Comment: @PeterSanctus There's really too much to mention in a comment, but the thing is there's a slight abuse of notation and terminology going on. If we want to be really formal, then what is going on is that for each point $p \in \Bbb{R}^3$, the vectors $\hat{r}(p),\hat{\phi}(p),\hat{\theta}(p)$ are elements of what is known as the tangent space $T_p\Bbb{R}^3$. And these form a basis for that particular tangent space. If you go to a different point $q \in \Bbb{R}^3$, then the tangent vectors there $T_q\Bbb{R}^3$ is a completely different vector space.

Comment: at each point, there is a different tangent space, which is why you may have heard the statement "the spherical basis vectors vary from point to point". But where the confusion begins is when people start using isomorphisms of $\Bbb{R}^3 \cong T_p\Bbb{R}^3$. By the way, I'm not saying that the other basis vectors are redundant at all. They're very important. It's just that if you take a point $p \in \Bbb{R}^3$, and consider it's image point in $T_p\Bbb{R}^3$ (under the isomorphism $\xi_p: \Bbb{R}^3 \to T_p\Bbb{R}^3$) then $\xi_p(p) = \lVert p\rVert \hat{r}(p)$

Comment: However, if you consider the same point $p \in \Bbb{R}^3$, but if you consider its image in a different tangent space $T_q\Bbb{R}^3$, namely $\xi_q(p)$ (i.e draw a dot in space; call this point $p$. Now, imagine drawing the arrow from the origin to the point $p$, now "transport" that arrow so that the tail starts at the point $q$; this is what I mean by $\xi_q(p)$). Then, in this case, $\xi_q(p)$ will be a linear combination of all three basis vectors $\hat{r}(q), \hat{\phi}(q), \hat{\theta}(q)$. So, you see, the other two basis vectors are very important.

Comment: So, part of your confusion comes from the fact that in the usual notation of $\hat{r}, \hat{\phi}$ and $\vec{r}$, people suppress the dependence of these vectors on the point they "originate from" (i.e they don't explicitly mention that we're looking at different tangent spaces). So, not making these things explicit is a huge part of the confusion (and also not explicitly clarifying the various isomorphisms which are used).

Comment: so $r \cdot \hat r$ points to the origin of the considered tangent space. when I now add up those $\phi$ and $\theta$ components as I did in my orgininal calculation, I end up at a point shifted by $\pi /2$ in the $\theta$-direction and by $\pi /4$ in the $\phi$-direction to the origin of the tangent space?

Comment: thanks, anyways, for your clarification of these matters =)

Comment: Sort of. Roughly speaking, $\hat{r}(p)$ is a vector of length 1, whose direction is from the origin to the point $p$, and we think of it as "having the tail at the point $p$". So, $r \, \hat{r}(p)$ is the vector with length $r$, and direction is from $0$ to $p$, but with the tail beginning at $p$. Now, if you add things like $\pi/2 \, \hat{\theta}(p)$ to $r\, \hat{r}(p)$, you get another vector (again with the tail starting at $p$), but it points in a different direction and has a different length.

Comment: again, I've been somewhat purposely vague regarding the distinction between "point" and "vector", because the "definitions" you may see in introductory courses are very vague, but at the same time, I'm not sure I should just dump a whole bunch of definitions on you (because they require a bit of background to develop properly). Anyway,don't worry too much if you didn't understand every single subtle distinction I tried to make (I always had a "working understanding" of these matters but only properly clarified the fine details for myself after having taken a course in differential geometry)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to spherical coordinates, you need to do the following

1. Calculate distance from origin - $r$

$$r = ||p|| = \sqrt 2$$

2. Calculate $\theta$ - angle made by position vector with z-axis: Since the vector is in $xy$ plane, this angle will be $\frac{\pi}{2}$
3. Calculate $\phi$ - angle made by projection of position vector onto $xy$ plane with x-axis: Since the vector is already in the x-y plane, the projection is itself, and it makes an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ with it

Hence, point in $(r,\theta, \phi)$ system is $(\sqrt 2, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{4})$, which is what you have got in the calculations. What you did after that I do not understand